# How to convert Sars-CoV-2 ORF1ab codon positions to ORF1b positions?

Tags: sars-cov-2, covid-19, codon, nomenclature, orf

Some websites mention amino acid mutations as ORF1ab, most however use ORF1a/b instead.

So how can I translate from one to the other? What do I need to subtract from say `ORF1ab:4588I` to get the corresponding `N` in `ORF1b:<N>I`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORF1ab:4588I` corresponds to `ORF1b:187I` so one needs to subtract `4401` to go from `1ab` to `1b` and add `4401` to go the other way.

Comment: Just for clarification: 1a or 1b? You reference 1b in the question but answer with 1a.

Comment: You're right, I fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is now an Open Source online tool that does the conversion, [Codon2Nucleotide](https://codon2nucleotide.theo.io/) by Theo Sanderson.